# Are DNA molecules negatively charged at low pH values?

Tags: biochemistry, dna, organic-chemistry, nucleic-acids, phosphate

We know, that for each monomer of DNA, phosphate groups are having -1 charge because one of the oxygen is negatively charged (2nd oxygen participates in the phosphodiester covalent bond), but isn't it really depends on PH level? and if it does, for some PH level of X, for every N base pairs of DNA, how many phosphate groups are charged?

To better interpret what I mean, let me draw this scenario: If the solution contains too many protons (so PH is very low), would DNA still will be charged? why the negatively charged oxygens would not take these hydrogen ions, and makes them bond as hydrogens by sharing additional electron?

[image: phosphate groups at low PH]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. At a ph<5 which is where the PI of DNA breaks down, the phosphate group will bind protons, while the nitrogenous bases will become positively charged owing to the acidic environment.